# Slow wired connection speed with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: connection

Please,I have Acer Aspire One AOA150/ZG5,I'd like to understand if the connection speed is not too slow -25/30 Mbps WIRED- and how I can  check if there is something wrong,because I'm a beginner.I installed 16.04LTS at the end of the year.With Windows my WIRED connection speed is about 280-290 Mbps.Thank you